# Background color looks so flat?

Tags: html, css, colors, background-color

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> About </title>
</head><style>
body
{
background-color:#00FFFF;
}
</style>
```

I know how to add background color, but it looks so flat and so 1990's looking.. how would i add like a polish to the color?

Comment: By the way, it's 2013. [Flat design is in](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/09/03/flat-and-thin-are-in/).

Comment: a gradient and I Know, it's 2013, some people choose to be different.

Answer (score 2):

This is a question that people will have a hard time answering here because it is very vague and has most likely been posted many times. I will give you an answer with the caveat that I hope you will search for an answer to a similar question next time before just posting a question that has been answered many times.

Obviously you would make that background a gradient and simply fade from one color to another color that is slightly lighter or darker. Here is code that should work in most browsers:

```
    html {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#00FFFF, #00b2b2);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px hsla(0,0%,0%,.3);
    min-height: 100%;
```

I have made a codepen here for you to play around with. There are many different ways to include this code into your site as css, you may also want to look into a solution that covers all browsers. Again, please search this site first because the answers are already here.

http://codepen.io/httpJunkie/pen/HcGpq

Comment: Change the `0.3` in `hsla(0,0%,0%,.3);` to `0.2` or `0.5` to see how that effects the box shadow, this is what I think you are looking for. It not only has your color fading down to a darker color of the same hue, but also implements a box shadow for some slight but not gaudy depth.

Comment: Did anyone answer your question correctly? You should check the green arrow underneath the up & down arrows of the most correct answer or the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

- CSS3 [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)
- CSS3 [gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient) ([`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient), [`radial-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient), [`repeating-linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient))

Answer (score 0):

A gradient would look more beautiful

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> About </title>
    </head><style>
    body {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#87e0fd), color-stop(40%,#53cbf1), color-stop(100%,#05abe0));
    }
    </style>
```

This code will work in chrome and safari.  For cross browser compatibility you can create your colors online at http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/